# I am trying to draw random numbers until a certain number is found, but why isn't my for-loop counter working?

Tags: javascript

I am completing an assignment for my Intro CS course. For this assignment, we must fix a javascript function so that it extracts values for variables, initializes a counter, and produces a loop that continues to increase in count until a certain number is found. My problem is that my version of the code does not seem to work.

For the current version that I will detail below, I extracted the variables from each of the 'num' textboxes and began constructing the for-loop action, where in which the count will increase whenever a 4-digit number is produced that is not the values inside the extracted 'num' textboxes. I've tested this same code a few times, even with the 'count' variables inside of the condition statements changed to 'i' variables and nothing works.

I am working with the random.js library--found here ( http://balance3e.com/random.js )--to randomize the looping 'picks'.

I have also tried other loop versions, including the normal while-loop, and the do/while-loop.

My professor has inadequately taught the material and appears "too busy" to help, so I apologize if some of the code is just flat-out wrong. I tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PICK-4 Lotto</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="random.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">      

    function DrawUntilWinner()
    // Assumes: user has entered 4 numbers in pick boxes      
    // Results: repeatedly generates pick-4 winners until match user pick      
    {
        var num1, num2, num3, num4, pick1, pick2, pick3, pick4, count;

        num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
        num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
        num3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num3').value);
        num4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num4').value);

        for (count = 1; count > 0; count++) {
            pick1 = RandomInt(0, 9); 
            pick2 = RandomInt(0, 9);
            pick3 = RandomInt(0, 9);
            pick4 = RandomInt(0, 9);

            if (pick1 != num1 || pick2 != num2 || pick3 != num3 || pick4 != num4) {
                count ++;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 'The number of picks needed to get '
                + num1 + '-' + num2 + '-' + num3 + '-' + num4 + ' was ' + count;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h2>Pick-4 Lotto</h2>
        <p>
            This page demonstrates the futility of lotteries. <br> Click on
            the button to perform LOTTO drawings until <input type="text"
                id="num1" size=1 value=0> <input type="text" id="num2"
                size=1 value=0> <input type="text" id="num3" size=1 value=0>
            <input type="text" id="num4" size=1 value=0> appears.
        </p>
        <input type="button" value="Click to begin drawing"
            onclick="DrawUntilWinner()">
        <hr>
        <div id="outputDiv"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The correct code should display something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJEKI.jpg

But instead of the ending '0' under the horizontal rule being '0', it would be the total 'count' it took to get the extracted 4-digit number after the loop.

Thank you for any and all assistance!

Comment: What is `RandomInt`? There's no in-built method of doing that - you'd have to use `Math.random`.

Comment: @JackBashford the asker is using a library. And yes, it's an overkill.

Comment: You're never exiting the loop after picking the right number (creating an infinite loop). After your `if` block, where you count up, add `else break;` to exit the loop if the pick matches.

Comment: Besides never exciting the loop you are double counting since count is incremented by the for loop then in the if block too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
for (count = 1; count > 0; count++) {
    pick1 = RandomInt(0, 9); 
    pick2 = RandomInt(0, 9);
    pick3 = RandomInt(0, 9);
    pick4 = RandomInt(0, 9);

    if (pick1 != num1 || pick2 != num2 || pick3 != num3 || pick4 != num4) {
        count ++;
    }
}
```

with something like this:

```
count = 0;

do {

    pick1 = RandomInt(0, 9); 
    pick2 = RandomInt(0, 9);
    pick3 = RandomInt(0, 9);
    pick4 = RandomInt(0, 9);

    count++;

} while (pick1 != num1 || pick2 != num2 || pick3 != num3 || pick4 != num4);
```

Comment: Your solution helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are never getting out of your for loop, so your program just loops for ever.

You should break out of your for loop when you find the correct match, something like this:

**Edit:** Also, as @trognanders pointed out, you're incrementing `counter` twice: one time in your for loop declaration, and another time inside the if statement.

```
for (count = 1; count > 0; count++) {
            pick1 = RandomInt(0, 9); 
            pick2 = RandomInt(0, 9);
            pick3 = RandomInt(0, 9);
            pick4 = RandomInt(0, 9);

            if (pick1 == num1 || pick2 == num2 || pick3 == num3 || pick4 == num4) {
                break;
            }
}
```

P.S.: In your scenario, you might consider using a while loop, as you are looping as long as a condition is met, and not for a fixed number of iterations:

```
var counter = 1;
while(pick1 != num1 || pick2 != num2 || pick3 != num3 || pick4 != num4) {
  //as long as the number does not match, keep looping
  counter++;
  //re-pick random numbers
}
```

Comment: So, I see how the code you provided would work, but the overall result doesn't display once I've added your resolved code. Perhaps something else is broken within my code?